Exporting 3x3 patches from Earth Engine
I have a csv with GPS coordinates. For each row in my csv I want to export a 3x3 patch from a sentinel-2 image. This is what my code looks like:
points = ee.FeatureCollection('path/to/csv')
columns = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B9', 'B11', 'B12']
year = "2018"
month = "4"
next_ = "5"
img = (ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
    .filterDate(f'{year}-{month}-01', f'{year}-{next_}-01')
    .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', False)
    .mosaic())

def export_patch(feature):
    point = feature.geometry()
    # Buffer by 15 meters to approximate a 3x3 pixel area.
    rectangle = point.buffer(15).bounds()
    # Clip the image to this rectangle.
    clipped_image = img.clip(rectangle).select(columns)
    name = ee.String("S2_").cat(feature.get('POINT_ID')).cat(ee.String(f"_{month}_")).cat(ee.String(year))
    # Export the image to Google Drive.
    task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(
        image=clipped_image,
        description=name,
        folder='LUCAS', 
        fileNamePrefix=name,  
        scale=10,
        region=rectangle,
        fileFormat='GeoTIFF',
        maxPixels=1e6 
    )
    task.start()
points.map(export_patch)

However I get this error when I try to start my task
ee.ee_exception.EEException: A mapped function's arguments cannot be used in client-side operations
I've tried to set the description and fileNamePrefix paramters to be static strings, however I keep getting the error is there anything else in my code that might be the cause of the issue? If yes how can I fix it?

This is a Client vs Server error. Export is a client-side function and, as the error states, client-side operations cannot be used in mapped functions (which happen in the server). Please see https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server & https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/debugging#mapped-functions.
One workaround is to use Export in a client function (e.g. for loop). For example, you can swap your export_patch function with the code below:
# Number of points.
n = points.size().getInfo()

# Make the feature collection a list.
points_list = points.toList(n)

for i in list(range(n)):
  point = ee.Feature(points_list.get(i)).geometry()
  # Buffer by 15 meters to approximate a 3x3 pixel area.
  rectangle = point.buffer(15).bounds()
  # Clip the image to this rectangle.
  clipped_image = img.clip(rectangle).select(columns)
  name = 'S2_'+ee.Feature(points_list.get(i)).get('POINT_ID').getInfo()+f'_{month}_'+year
  task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(
      image=clipped_image,
      description=name,
      folder='LUCAS',
      fileNamePrefix=name,
      scale=10,
      region=rectangle,
      fileFormat='GeoTIFF',
      maxPixels=1e6
  ) 
  task.start()
  print(f"Export image {name}")

I'm not sure how your 'POINT_ID' property is set up, so you may need to adjust the name argument as needed. For example, if it is a number, you may need to convert it to a string.
To test it out, add a break function at the bottom of the for loop (after the print statement). This will allow just the first export to happen. Once you see it works, you can remove or comment break to run all the exports.
